# Are robustness and generalizability the same thing?

Tags: machine-learning, inference, estimators, robust

An optimal parameter $\theta^*$ is robust if it does not change much when calculated for different samples of data from a population.

$\theta^*$ has good generalizability if its predictive power remains good for different samples of test data.

These feel like different wordings of the same concept. Is there some subtle difference I am overlooking?

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't understand same things from these explanations. For example, a constant predictor is a robust one, but it's probably not a good predictor.

Comment: Good point. Could you explain what is difference in their definitions?

Comment: @900edges in the first one, it says the parameter estimate doesn't change much, but this tells us nothing about the quality of the estimate, as my constant predictor example.

Comment: Right, so an estimator could be very robust but be a bad predictor. But it could be a consitently a bad predictor, so its generalizability should technically be high? Or is a predictor only "generalizable" if it is good for the train set *and* the test set?

Comment: Yes, a bad predictor won’t be generalizable.